# Issue with saving 3D array to file

Tags: c

For class I have made a chess game where I am trying to save the current board state to a csv file.

I am using the following code:

```
    mkdir("saves");
FILE *fp1 = fopen_s(&fp1, "saves/board.csv", "wb");  //create a file
if (fp1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
    perror("Error: ");
    return 0;
}

fwrite(board, sizeof(char), sizeof(board), fp1);
fclose(fp1);
```

but it is erroring out on the fp1 == null. The perror is printing out "File exists" and it won't go any further. It creates the file (so if i change board.csv to something else that file would be created) but no data is saved to it. I don't understand why the file existing is causing it to error as surely it knows it just created it to write?

The board is initalised as as board[8][8][2].

Any help with this would be great :)

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen_s`.  It returns 0 if successful.

Comment: @MFisherKDX how would I go about doing this? I set a breakpoint on the line where fp1 = fopen_s and checked the value of fp1. It says fp1 -> _Placeholder - <unable to read memory> as the value.

Comment: see my answer for more details

Comment: Your code is invalid. The compiler clearly told you what the problem is. Did you just ignore the diagnostic message? The return value of `fopen_s` is an integer. It cannot be used to initialize a `FILE *` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen_s` returns 0 if successful.  So your code:

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen_s(&fp1, "saves/board.csv", "wb");  //create a file
if (fp1 == NULL) {
    printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
```

is wrong in that on success it overwrites the value `fp1` to zero and prints out

> Error while opening the file.

Instead try

```
FILE *fp1 = NULL;
errno_t ret = fopen_s(&fp1, "saves/board.csv", "wb");
if (!ret) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `fopen_s` function incorrectly.  The function is declared as:

```
errno_t fopen_s(   
   FILE** pFile,  
   const char *filename,  
   const char *mode   
);
```

You're assigning the return value, which is an error code, to your file descriptor.  Assuming the function returns successfully, the returned value is 0.  When assigning this value to a pointer, it's the same as assigning NULL.

You should instead just check the return value without assigning it to `fp1`:

```
FILE *fp1;
if (fopen_s(&fp1, "saves/board.csv", "wb"))
{
    ...
```